# upload video to facebook page with graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I have plan to implement upload video in my website.i have page in facebook also.so when user upload video in my website,the video store in my facebook page.i already try use this http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload,but only me as admin of facebook page can upload video, otherwise 'invalid token' result. Can tell me with this case ??? Thanks for your replay

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the code on your link http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/515/#video_upload):

```
  // Find the access token for the page to which we want to post the video.
  foreach($accounts as $account) {
       if($account['id'] == $page_id) {
         $access_token = $account['access_token'];
         break;
       }
  }
```

The user logging in MUST be an admin of the page to upload a video.  Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: :thx for your replay, i know for that, can modified so public user(not only admin) allow to upload video also???

Comment: Nope. As I stated *"The user logging in MUST be an admin of the page to upload a video. Otherwise it won't work."*

Comment: this the result
{
   "id": "218479331585523"
}
can i redirect page after upload??(not display like above)

Comment: Please ask this new "redirection" question in a new stackoverflow question.  If my answer was correct, please click the checkmark beside it to close this current question on how to upload a video.  Thank you.